# run cypress shell with report on failed test cases

Tags: cypress

when running test with cypress using `cypress run` I can know whether the the spec file passed or failed but there is no extra information in which what test cases failed. is there any way to get more information about which test cases failed or succee[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `reporter` option in your Cypress config to set the type of report generated by Cypress.

Note: If you are running multiple specs via `cypress run`, they will overwrite each other [unless you include [hash]](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/tooling/reporters#Merging-reports-across-spec-files) in the file name.

```js
...
reporter: 'junit',
reporterOptions: {
  mochaFile: 'results/my-test-output-[hash].xml'
},
...
```